# What does a form w/ file input field HTTP's request look like?

Tags: file, http, header

What does a HTTP header with attached file look like (Client to Server file) and how do I parse that in, for example in .NET (minor question, experienced with RegEx and Streams etc.)

Comment: Find out yourself: download fiddler and do a file upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uploads from an HTML webform uses an HTTP `POST` request and the MIME `multipart/form-data` content type, which is defined in the HTML specifications (I've added HTTP headers to the examples shown in the specs):

HTML4: [Section 17 Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html) - [17.13.4 Form content types](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) - [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

> Note. Please consult [RFC2388] for additional information about file uploads, including backwards compatibility issues, the relationship between "multipart/form-data" and other content types, performance issues, etc.
>
> ...
>
> The content "multipart/form-data" follows the rules of all multipart MIME data streams as outlined in [RFC2045]. The definition of "multipart/form-data" is available at the [IANA] registry.
>
> ...
>
> The following example illustrates "multipart/form-data" encoding. Suppose we have the following form:
>
> ```
> <FORM action="http://server.com/cgi/handle"
>       enctype="multipart/form-data"
>       method="post">
>   <P>
>   What is your name? <INPUT type="text" name="submit-name"><BR>
>   What files are you sending? <INPUT type="file" name="files"><BR>
>   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
> </FORM>
> ```
>
> If the user enters "Larry" in the text input, and selects the text file "file1.txt", the user agent might send back the following data:
>
> ```
> POST /cgi/handle HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.com
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x
> Content-Length: ...
>
> --AaB03x
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"
>
> Larry
> --AaB03x
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
> Content-Type: text/plain
>
> ... contents of file1.txt ...
> --AaB03x--
> ```
>
> If the user selected a second (image) file "file2.gif", the user agent might construct the parts as follows:
>
> ```
> POST /cgi/handle HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.com
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x
> Content-Length: ...
>
> --AaB03x
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"
>
> Larry
> --AaB03x
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BbC04y
>
> --BbC04y
> Content-Disposition: file; filename="file1.txt"
> Content-Type: text/plain
>
> ... contents of file1.txt ...
> --BbC04y
> Content-Disposition: file; filename="file2.gif"
> Content-Type: image/gif
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> ...contents of file2.gif...
> --BbC04y--
> --AaB03x--
> ```

HTML5: [Section 4.10 Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html) - [4.10.22 Form submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#form-submission-0) - [4.10.22.7 Multipart form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#multipart-form-data)

> On the other hand, consider this form:
>
> ```
> <form action="/find.cgi" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
>   <input type=text name=t>
>   <input type=search name=q>
>   <input type=submit>
> </form>
> ```
>
> Given the same user input, the result on submission is quite different: the user agent instead does an HTTP POST to the given URL, with as the entity body something like the following text:
>
> ```
> POST /find.cgi HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.com
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----kYFrd4jNJEgCervE
> Content-Length: ...
>
> ------kYFrd4jNJEgCervE
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="t"
>
> cats
> ------kYFrd4jNJEgCervE
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="q"
>
> fur
> ------kYFrd4jNJEgCervE--
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The order of parts must be the same as the order of fields in the form data set. Multiple entries with the same name must be treated as distinct fields.
>
> Note: In particular, this means that multiple files submitted as part of a single `<input type=file multiple>` element will result in each file having its own field; **the "sets of files" feature ("multipart/mixed") of RFC 2388 is not used.**

Read the following RFCs for more details on how HTTP and MIME are handled in general:

[RFC 2045 Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Part One: Format of Internet Message Bodies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046)

[RFC 2046 Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Part Two: Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046)
(in particular, [Section 5.1 Multipart Media Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1))

[RFC 2047 MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) Part Three: Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)

[RFC 2388 Returning Values from Forms:  multipart/form-data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388)

[RFC 2616 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)